# Quantum numbers of a symmetry generator?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, symmetry-breaking, goldstone-mode

I am trying to understand the italicized part: a broken symmetry leads to a massless Goldstone boson *with same quantum numbers as broken symmetry generator*. Weinberg talks about it in Chapter 19, if you need a reference. Please let me know if you have deeper insight into this.